# "anachronistic crom" messages when booting up

Tags: installation, boot, restart

My screen shows this message when I try to start Xubuntu:

```
startind anachronistic crom
stopping anachronistic crom
checking battery state
stopping system V runlevel compatibility
starting
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get remove anacron
```